# selenium phantomJS download custom OCR image(aspx extension)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a login screen consisting of username, password and security code. My goal is to use the technologies such as selenium, phantonJs and download the OCR code on the login screen to the computer as a picture.
However, as stated in the following code, the  tag has the src aspx extension. therefore, when I call the aspx path in this src with the webclient, a different OCR image is descended.
My goal is only to download the code on the screen as a picture on my computer How can I do this? Thank you

```
[![<div>

                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="txtLoginName" type="text" id="txtLoginName" class="form-control" ><span id="RequiredFieldValidator1">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" ><span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" >*</span>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <img id="imgCap" src="./login_files/RetCap.aspx" style="height:30px;width:100px;border-width:0px;">
                                    <input name="txtCap" type="text" id="txtCap" class="form-control" >
                                </div>



</div>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a screenshot at that element and save it using `FileUtils.copyFile()` from lib `Apache Commons IO` ([here is a link with repository of lib, you have the option to download directly as jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io))

This is the way you can take screenschot at a particular element.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='imgCap']"));

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)elem).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File( "path/where/to/save.jpg" ));
```

P.S.: If you want to take screenshot to entire browser, change `(TakesScreenshot)elem` with `driver`